# How to get from a hashset all the elements that are of a particular subclass in c#?

Tags: c#

Lets say we have the classes Animal, Dog and Cat.  Dog and Cat both extend Animal.

```
public class Animal{}  
public class Dog : Animal{}  
public class Cat : Animal{}
```

Then we make a hashset of animals and populate it with both cats and dogs.

```
HashSet<Animal> animals = new HashSet<Animal>();  
animals.Add(new Dog());  
animals.Add(new Cat());  
animals.Add(new Dog());  
animals.Add(new Cat());
```

What is the best way to get a hashset or list of all the dogs (and nothing but the dogs) contained in the hashset animals?

Comment: You can search in a `HashSet<>` only for exact equality, not for "similar to"... So you'll have to enumerate all the `HashSet<>`

Comment: Like `var dogs = animals.Where(x => x is Dog)`

Comment: `animals.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Dog));`

Comment: Or: `animals.OfType<Dog>()`

Comment: @Juraboros what are you trying to do? If you want to process all items based on their type, a simple loop with a bit of pattern matching is easy and clean. If you want to process only cats or only dogs, you'll have to iterate over everyting or use a different container. Such a request would be rather unusual. Even `OfType<Dog>()` iterates over the source applying the type as a filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ for this.

```
var dogs = animals.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Dog)).ToList();
```

or shorter and with null handling

```
var dogs = animals.Where(x => x is Dog).ToList();
```

[101 LINQ examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: There are two subtle differences between the two line... `null` handling and what happens if there is a `class Bulldog : Dog {}`

Comment: Or `.OfType<Dog>()`

Comment: @xanatos Ok, null handling is better with the second line. 
A Bulldog is a Dog, isn't it? ;) And as long as Juraboros don't have Bulldogs or Siam cats we shold not make it more complicate than it is.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom When you write two solutions, and then write "or shorter", you are implying equivalence. I don't say that they wrong. They are both correct (as is the `.OfType<Dog>()`), but in many cases where you don't simply have dogs and cats they are subtly different. The first solution is a `==`, the second solution is a `>=`. No one would say that `==` is the same as `>=`

Comment: I totally agree with you, that's why i edited my post. Forgot about the null handling.